# Comparing char* in C++ lexicographically

Tags: c++, char, compare

I know that I can compare `string` by `<` `>` etc. but how to compare `char*` lexicographically?

Comment: Maybe too obvious, but... [`std::lexicographical_compare()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) springs to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Read here: [std::lexicographical_compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/) has two form

default (1):

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2>
  bool lexicographical_compare (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                                InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2);
```

custom (2):

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class Compare>
  bool lexicographical_compare (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                                InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2,
                                Compare comp);
```

Lexicographical less-than comparison

> Returns true if the range [first1,last1) compares lexicographically less than the range [first2,last2).